# Looping through items and place results in 3 columns

Tags: php

I am looping through my db results and output them in 3 columns. The final result needs to be like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   Item<br>
   Item<br>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   Item<br>
   Item<br>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   Item<br>
</div>
```

The number of items vary from 1 to over a hundred. Here's my shot at it:

```
$total = count($listArr);
$coln1 = ceil($total / 3);
$coln2 = $coln1 * 2;
$count = 0;

foreach ($listArr AS $lst) {

    if ($count == 0) {
        echo '
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
    } elseif(($count == $coln1 || $count == $coln2) && $count > 1) {
        echo '
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
    }

    echo $lst->item;

    if ($count == $total) {
        echo '
        </div>';
    }

    $count++;
}
```

There appears to be a logic error somewhere. It seem to work most of the time but there are cases where the div is not closed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to split your `$listArr` into required amount of chunks. After that you may concatenate them with [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
Given you have some kind of objects in your initial array you may use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to retrieve property values you want to display.

```
foreach (array_chunk($listArr, 3) as $chunk) {
    echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">',
        implode(
            '<br>',
            array_map(
                function ($list) {
                    return $list->item;
                },
                $chunk
            )
        ),
        '</div>';
}
```

Answering the actual question you've asked: you will never reach internals of this conditional statement:

```
if ($count == $total) {
    echo '
    </div>';
}
```

You will be out of the loop right before `$count` reaches `$total`.
If you really want to keep your solution you may fix it like this:

```
if ($count == $total - 1) {
    echo '
    </div>';
}
```

or by decrementing `$total` before the start of the loop. Although in my opinion the solution I provided above should be clearer.